# Why is font-size: 16px bigger in Internet Explorer 11 than in FireFox?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, font-size, internet-explorer-11

As viewed in Firefox 29:

[image]

As viewed in Internet Explorer 11:

[image]

I tried using `em` and `%` but the same result. Internet Explorer is always bigger than FireFox (tested Internet Explorer 8, 9, 10 and 11, all the same). Tried changing Internet Explorer text size under view in the menu with no results there either.

CSS is a modified _s for WordPress and this is inside `#primary-navigation`.

Edits per comments:

- Zoom is set to 100% (across browsers).
- Chrome looks fine.
- IE text size is set to medium.

EDITS 2016-12

Many comments requesting the actual CSS. The original CSS has been lost to time but `font-family` was indeed the issue. This is the corrected portion which uses Google fonts with a number of fallbacks which the client has approved.

```
ul.menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
    font-family: 'Noto Serif',Palatino,"Palatino Linotype",Georgia,serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 29px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
}
```

Comment: Did you look if the Zoom is at 100% on both browsers?

Comment: Check to make sure it's implicitly set to `16px` and IE is reading that value (Hint: Use developer tools to view the loaded font-size).  Also hit CTRL + 0 in both browsers to make sure your zoom is set to 100%.

Comment: What does the CSS look like? What font is that?

Comment: It *couldn't* be a zooming issue - the images that are (partially) visible are exactly the same size in both screenshots. It more likely has to do with the font size preference as @JakeGould mentioned.

Comment: It might also have to do with the font-family that each browser is using - they are clearly not using the same one, for some reason. In any case, in order to diagnose your problem we're going to need more than just screenshots and "CSS is a modified underscores theme".

Comment: How about a fiddle or link for us to check out?

Comment: They're different programs that render differently..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browsers are using different font faces. You can see this by comparing the glyphs. For example, the letter “l” is clearly different. The font size is the same, but the font designs are different. It is up to font designer to decide how big glyphs are relative to the font size.

Comment: thanks, @BoltClock mentioned this in the comments. I think it is correct, I will accept the answer once I have had a chance to check it.

Comment: I changed the `font-family` to something else and they are exactly the same as each other now. Problem solved.